# React setState not updating properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
this.setState({ selected: 0 }, () => {
    console.log("selected value: " + this.state.selected);
});
```

This prints values other than zero depending on what value `selected` was before running this code. Basically the setState does nothing and I'm not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit - Here is some more code**

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var selected = 0;

    this.state = {
      selected: selected
    };

    this.handleTap = this.handleTap.bind(this);
  }

  deselect() {
    this.setState({ selected: 0 }, () => {
      console.log("selected: " + this.state.selected);
    }); 
  }

  handleTap() {
    var selected = this.state.selected;

    selected++;

    if(selected >= 2) {
      this.deselect();
    }

    this.setState({selected: selected});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onPointerDown={() => this.handleTap()} style={{width: "100px", height: "100px", backgroundColor: "black"}}></div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I now believe I know the issue. I think calling setState in `handleTap()` after calling `deselect()` is making the selected value stay at a value greater than two.

Comment: That should work, and always print 0. Gonna need more context, there's no issue with the few lines you've posted

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. There is nearly non-existent context here. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that accurately reproduces your issue. Typically you will need to include an entire component so we can trace when and where your state mutates.

Comment: Cool bug, can you show us more of the related code? It would help to see the containing component and it's constructor.

Comment: You can click on the edit button, and edit your question. Give us more code

Comment: I believe you are correct about what the problem is. Test it out and if you're right you should probably remove the question from SO because it's not likely to help anyone in the future. Great that the problem is solved, though.

Comment: @SydneyY I can't unfortunately. I get the message "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it" when trying to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here

```
if(selected >= 2) {
  this.deselect();
}

this.setState({selected: selected});
```

The `deselect()` sets the state, and the right afterward, you call another `setState` to the selected value. It can be fixed by simply adding a `else` statement (so the `console.log` inside the callback will always be 0 - after you `setState` to 0)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var selected = 0;

    this.state = {
      selected: selected
    };
  }

  deselect() {
    this.setState({ selected: 0 }, () => {
      console.log("selected: " + this.state.selected);
    }); 
  }

  handleTap() {
    var selected = this.state.selected;

    selected++;

    if (selected >= 2) {
      this.deselect();
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ selected: selected });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        onPointerDown={() => this.handleTap()}
        style={{ color: "white", width: "100px", height: "100px", backgroundColor: "black" }}
      >
        State: {this.state.selected}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is `handleTap`. React state updates are asynchronous and "collated", meaning, calling `setState` several times within a single function means they all get queued up and processed.

```
handleTap() {
  var selected = this.state.selected;

  selected++;

  if(selected >= 2) {
    this.deselect();
  }

  this.setState({selected: selected});
}
```

Here you are setting state twice, but since you aren't doing functional updates using the previous state, the last `setState` call trumps all previous calls.

You should instead only call one `setState` per tap handle.

```
handleTap() {
  var selected = this.state.selected;

  console.log("current selected", selected);

  selected++;

  if (selected >= 2) {
    this.deselect();
  } else {
    this.setState({ selected: selected });
  }
}
```

[image: Edit affectionate-pascal-w19ng]

Answer (score -2):

The problem was after the if condition, adding an else as shown below would solve the problem.

```
    handleTap() {
      var selected = this.state.selected;
      selected++;
      if(selected >= 2) {
        this.deselect();
      } else {
      this.setState({selected: selected});
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, have edited the answer after more code was shown and identified the problem. Right now it is set to work as expected.